# Qiskit experiments on qiskit IBM runtime

Tags: qiskit, state-tomography, qiskit-runtime

I'm trying to perform a state tomography on a quantum circuit using [Qiskit experiments](https://qiskit.org/ecosystem/experiments/dev/manuals/verification/state_tomography.html). I was able to perform the tomography on the AerSimulator but have still not been able to do the tomography on real quantum hardware using [Qiskit IBM runtime](https://qiskit.org/ecosystem/ibm-runtime/index.html).

```
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import QiskitRuntimeService
from qiskit_experiments.library import StateTomography
from qiskit.visualization import plot_state_city

service = QiskitRuntimeService()
backend = service.get_backend("ibmq_belem")
st = StateTomography(qc)
stdata = st.run(backend, shots=1000).block_for_results()
state_result = stdata.analysis_results("state")
plot_state_city(state_result.value)
```

`qc` is just any quantum circuit. The error I am getting is

```
IBMBackend.run() is not supported in the Qiskit Runtime environment.
```

Is there any way of getting this to work or is it just not supported yet?